# How to create Subscription with Laravel 6 and Cashier 10 with Stripe?

Tags: php, subscription, laravel-6, laravel-cashier

Laravel Developers,

After I submit my payment form, I get a 404 error message. When I check the database there is no update in the subscription document. Any suggestions? I've been at this for a while now and I feel like I'm missing something that should be obvious.

**SubscriptionController.php**

```php
class SubscriptionController extends Controller
{
    public function create(Request $request, Plan $plan)
    {
        $plan = Plan::findOrFail($request->get('plan'));

        $request->user()
            ->newSubscription('main', $plan->stripe_plan)
            ->create($request->stripeToken);

        return redirect()->route('home')
            ->with('success', 'Your plan subscribed successfully');
    }
}
```

**Here is my Route**

```
 Route::get('/plans', 'PlanController@index')->name('plans.index');
 Route::get('/plan/{plan}', 'PlanController@show')->name('plans.show');
```

Comment: what is your route path?

Comment: look here: https://github.com/haimiz/laravel-cashier-stripe

Comment: @HafezDivandari I added my route to the original post. What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using [Implicit Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#implicit-binding) on your route and controller. i.e. Laravel will automatically inject the model instance that has an ID matching the corresponding value from the request URI. If a matching model instance is not found in the database, a 404 HTTP response will automatically be generated.

But you're repeating this behavior using `findOrFail` and calling `$request->get('plan')` which is `null` because `plan` is not in your input request but it's on your route. So the `Plan::findOrFail(null)` leads to 404 error.

You can correct your code in 2 ways:

1. Remove unnecessary line that contains `findOrFail` and let Laravel handles it for you by *Implicit Binding* (I recommend this way):

   ```php
   class SubscriptionController extends Controller
   {
       public function create(Request $request, Plan $plan)
       {
           //$plan = Plan::findOrFail($request->get('plan')); // <= unnecessary

           $request->user()
               ->newSubscription('main', $plan->stripe_plan)
               ->create($request->stripeToken);

           return redirect()->route('home')
               ->with('success', 'Your plan subscribed successfully');
       }
   }
   ```
2. Change your route and controller's method to use `$id` instead of *Implicit Binding* and use `findOrFail` manually (not recommended):

   ```
   Route::get('/plan/{id}', 'PlanController@show')->name('plans.show');
   ```

   ```php
   class SubscriptionController extends Controller
   {
       public function create(Request $request, $id)
       {
           $plan = Plan::findOrFail($id);

           $request->user()
               ->newSubscription('main', $plan->stripe_plan)
               ->create($request->stripeToken);

           return redirect()->route('home')
               ->with('success', 'Your plan subscribed successfully');
       }
   }
   ```